# IE8 How to remove a parent DIV if the child IMG inside it has broken image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

The code below is working fine in FF, Chrome and IE9+.  However, I want to implement it in IE8 or even IE7. Current JQuery version is jQuery v2.1.1.

Target Output specific for IE8/IE7: - to be able to .remove() or display:none the parent DIV with class "column" whenever an image is unavailable. IMG1 has wrong src(zhttp://...) intentionally to trigger the error.

HTML:

```
<div class="column">
    <img src="xhttp://placehold.it/200x200&text=IMG1" onerror="imgError(this);" />
</div>
<div class="column">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=IMG2" onerror="imgError(this);" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
function imgError(image) {
    $(image).parent('div.column').css('display','none');
}
```

also JS:
JS:

```
function imgError(image) {
    $(image).parent('div.column').remove();
}
```

Sample: (I cannot test in IE8 browser though)
http://jsfiddle.net/philcyb/c0wfe7wv/21/

This maybe using similar code as the previous question that I posted, purposely for consistency and simplicity, but this question is intended for IE8 specifically.
Thanks in advance again.

Comment: [You should read this](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/). jQuery 2+ has no support for IE6/7/8. And that is a good thing.

Comment: @James Donnelly - I asked similar question earlier but I did not specify that it doesn't work in IE8.  And was advised to ask it in another question, thus, i posted this.  Apologies! I was hoping somebody in here experienced a work around.

Comment: @Philcyb I marked it as a duplicate because this does appear to have the same problem as the other question.

Comment: @James - Sorry but as new to this, I don't see answers to my question in this duplication question you mentioned: "img.onerror does not seem to work for IE8."  Can you simplify this like, does this mean, my question could not be answered or resolved in IE8? that's how i understand it.  thank you.

Comment: Your problem appears to be that `img.onerror` isn't being called in IE8.